# Airflow S3 connection type is missing

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm using the versions airflow 2.5.1 and python 3.10. I need to create S3 connection type in Admin>Add connection. But the connection Type for S3 in dropdown is missing.

I already installed the the provider apache-airflow-providers-amazon and also tried re-starting. But the issue remains. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using connection type Amazon Web Services. It worked with the same s3 hook.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 6 of the Amazon providers this connection type [has been removed](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/6.0.0/index.html#breaking-changes). As you've already found out, you can just use the Amazon Web Services connection type and specify s3 specific configuration in the connection's 'extra' field [like in this example](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html#s3-bucket-configurations)